# Solved: Mass uncheck the "exclude" option by images

Tags: import, product-images, importexport

We have imported a lot of products with Magmi in Magento 1 and accidentally checked all the "exlcude" options for our images, so the main image is not shown on the product page.

Is there an easy way to import a field to uncheck this option by all images?

Hope someone can help!

Comment: magento version 1.x or 2 .x

Comment: It is for Magento 1.x just placed it in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If you want to do it for all products, all images where it's excluded you can run following SQL query:

   ```
   UPDATE `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value` SET `disabled` = '0' WHERE `disabled` = '1';
   ```
2. Update your import files and add a + before the image (do it for all images - small and thumbnails too). Run the import again.